# Update JavaFX window in background

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, background

I'm currently working on a file explorer. I want to implement a search function, which displays all matching files within the current directory and all subdirectories. I tried it with the shell command 'find' but that didn't work. After that I tried to use Java 8 API's Files.walk(...) Function. That worked partially. I can now get all files and print them out. The only problem is, that i can't add a Pane in my GUI for every found file.

I tried it with one Task but the GUI does not update. In the final version, below, there are two threads. One that gets the files and fills them into a queue and the other polls objects from the queue and displays it on the GUI. From debugging, I know that the Queue always a size between 0 and 2. That means, my system is working. But the GUI still don't updates.

Could anyone help me please?

```
public static final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<FilePane> files = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

public void search(String key) {
        Task<Boolean> listLoader = new Task<Boolean>() {
        {
            setOnSucceeded(workerStateEvent -> {
                System.out.println("Done");
            });

            setOnFailed(workerStateEvent -> getException().printStackTrace());
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
            try {
                Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(currentDirectoryController().getDir().getAbsolutePath()), new HashSet<FileVisitOption>(Arrays.asList(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)),
                        Integer.MAX_VALUE, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                            @Override
                            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file , BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file , IOException e) throws IOException {
                                return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir , BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                                files.add(new FilePane(new KFile(dir.toFile()), cont));
                                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                            }
                        });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return true;
        }
    };

    Thread loader = new Thread(listLoader);
    loader.setDaemon(true);
    loader.start();

    new Thread(() -> {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            while(true) {
                if(!files.isEmpty()) {
                    fileContainer.getChildren().add(files.poll());
                }
            }
        });
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Thread(() -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        while(true) {
            if(!files.isEmpty()) {
                fileContainer.getChildren().add(files.poll());
            }
        }
    });
}).start();
```

This just starts a different thread that then posts a long-running task (in fact a infinite loop) to run on the application thread.

To not block the application thread you need to post only tasks that can be done quickly on the application thread.

Additional optimisations:

- To avoid posting too many tasks on the application thread in a short time, you could add a delay.
- You should have a way for the second thread to shut down. Otherwise the thread looking for new files published by the first thread will run forever. It would be a good idea to do the synchronisation yourself to ensure the flag indicating the task is done is not set to
- Try using a virtualized control like `ListView` or `TableView` to display the files. This avoids creating a huge amount of nodes in memory and also speeds up the layout, since it only needs to consider visible nodes.

Actually you could avoid the complexity of the consumer/producer implementation by simply using `Platform.runLater` from the original task:

```
Task<Boolean> listLoader = new Task<Boolean>() {
    {
        setOnSucceeded(workerStateEvent -> {
            System.out.println("Done");
        });

        setOnFailed(workerStateEvent -> getException().printStackTrace());
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(currentDirectoryController().getDir().getAbsolutePath()), new HashSet<FileVisitOption>(Arrays.asList(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)),
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                        @Override
                        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file , BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file , IOException e) throws IOException {
                            return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir , BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                            FilePane filePane = new FilePane(new KFile(dir.toFile()), cont);
                            Platform.runLater(() -> fileContainer.getChildren().add(filePane)); // TODO bulk updates to prevent posting runables too frequently
                            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                        }
                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }
};

Thread loader = new Thread(listLoader);
loader.setDaemon(true);
loader.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread(() -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        while(true) {
            if(!files.isEmpty()) {
                fileContainer.getChildren().add(files.poll());
            }
        }
    });
}).start();
```

this statement actually does following:

```
Runnable action1 = () -> {
        while(true) {
            if(!files.isEmpty()) {
                fileContainer.getChildren().add(files.poll());
            }
        };

Runnable action2 = () -> {
    Platform.runLater(action1);
};

new Thread(action2).start();
```

So, action2 executes very quickly, there is no sense to run it on a separate thread. action2, however, has an infinite loop and runs forever, and it runs on the GUI thread, actually blocking this thread and preventing it from rewdrawing the screen.

You have heard, probably, that you may not occupy the GUI thread for the long time. That is, you should execute the loop outside the GUI thread, something like this:

```
Runnable action1 = () -> {
        while(true) {
            Platform.runLater(
                fileContainer.getChildren().add(files.take());
            });
        };

new Thread(action1).start();
```

Now we see that this thread does very little - takes filepanes from the queue, wraps them in a simple method and puts to the input queue of the GUI thread. So it can be eliminated, and all the work can be done in the loader thread: instead of `files.add(new FilePane(...))` do

```
 Platform.runLater(
     fileContainer.getChildren().add(new FilePane(...));
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I implement the Files.walk(....) into this thread?

Comment: in fact, @fabian proposed exactly the same solution: remove second thread and feed the GUI thread from the loader thread directly. If you understand his answer and don't understand mine, just do as he proposed.